# Displaying the content of mysql in bootstrap table

Tags: mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm actually trying to show the content of my mysql table in a bootstrap table.

I can see the contents but it shows only the first content right the other contents are not inside the table. Where is here wrong?

How it looks actually:

[image]

My table.php

```
  <?php 
include('config/mysql.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM streams");
echo mysql_error();

?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/extra.css" />

<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0" > 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th class="header">ID</th> 
                    <th class="header">Name</th>
                    <th class="header">Port</th>
                    <th class="header">Options</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 

            <tbody>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                 <tr>           
                    <td bgcolor="#D1FFC2"><?php echo $row["id"] ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#D1FFC2"><?php echo $row["streamname"] ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#D1FFC2"><?php echo $row["streamport"] ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#D1FFC2">Debug- Delete- Edit</td>
                        </tr>      
            </tbody> 
            </table>


<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this out of the while $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) loop and put it after the end.

```
 </tbody> 
            </table>
```

And consider using mysqlI or PDO as mysql functions are depreciated and will be going away.

Answer (score 0):

Close the while after the "table row" `<TR>`

```
 <?php 
include('config/mysql.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM streams");
echo mysql_error();

?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/extra.css" />

<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0" > 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th class="header">ID</th> 
                    <th class="header">Name</th>
                    <th class="header">Port</th>
                    <th class="header">Options</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 

            <tbody>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                 <tr>           
                    <td bgcolor="#D1FFC2"><?php echo $row["id"] ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#D1FFC2"><?php echo $row["streamname"] ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#D1FFC2"><?php echo $row["streamport"] ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#D1FFC2">Debug- Delete- Edit</td>
                        </tr>  

<?php } ?>    
            </tbody> 
            </table>
```